# Python code to click next pages links and scrape all the page hyper links

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python, and i m struck in moving from one page to another, i am able to scrape one page details.
Below is the code i am using

```
def getURLinfo(url):
            url = "https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/MemberPages/MyAccounts.aspx?lang=eng"
            driver.get(url)
            html = driver.page_source
            nextpage = "ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl01$ctl01"
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

            while soup.find(id=re.compile(nextpage)):
                    for table in soup.findAll('table', {'id':'ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_itemPlaceholderContainer'} ):
                            for link in table.findAll('a'):
                                    link.findAll('a')
                                    print link['href']
                    driver.find_element_by_link_text(nextpage).click()
                    html = html + driver.page_source
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    driver.close()
```

I am not sure if i am n the correct track too.

Below is the html code
                    
                        View 
                    
                    
                        211538138800143
                    
                    
                        43-38 39 PLAC 35         
                    
                    
                        JUAN MENDOZA         
                    
                    
                        Active
                    
                    
                        Delete

```
          <tr style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
                <td>
                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl17_lnkSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl17$lnkSelect','')">View </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl17_lblAcctNumber">211558100500042</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl17_LblServiceAddress">41-12 41 ST ENTM         </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl17_LblCustName">41-12 41ST MGMT CORP.</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl17_LblAcctStatus">Active</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this account number?');" id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl17_lnkDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl17$lnkDelete','')">Delete </a>
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl18_lnkSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl18$lnkSelect','')">View </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl18_lblAcctNumber">211558102300045</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl18_LblServiceAddress">41-12 41 ST 1D           </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl18_LblCustName">41-12 MGMT CORP      </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl18_LblAcctStatus">Active</span>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this account number?');" id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl18_lnkDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl18$lnkDelete','')">Delete </a>
                </td>
            </tr>



          <tr style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
                <td>
                    <a id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl19_lnkSelect" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl19$lnkSelect','')">View </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl19_lblAcctNumber">211564295000053</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl19_LblServiceAddress">47-07 39 ST HLSM         </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl19_LblCustName">QPII-47-07 39 ST.,LLC</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl19_LblAcctStatus">Active</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this account number?');" id="ctl00_Main_lvMyAccount_ctrl19_lnkDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl19$lnkDelete','')">Delete </a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

                    </td>
</tr>
```

```
    </td>
</tr> 

<tr align="center"><td>
    <span id="ctl00_Main_DataPager1"><a disabled="disabled"><< </a>&nbsp;<span>1</span>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl01$ctl01','')">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl01$ctl02','')">3</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl01$ctl03','')">4</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl01$ctl04','')">5</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl01$ctl05','')">...</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$DataPager1$ctl02$ctl00','')"> >></a>&nbsp;</span> 

</td></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: how to move from page 1 to page 2

Comment: the link is https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/MemberPages/MyAccounts.aspx?lang=eng

Comment: Can't access it. Can you paste, 10 lines of the source code around the link?

Comment: i have pasted it. please check

Comment: I see a problem, it's a javascript-generated link, not just a link..

Comment: Are you trying to click on link with `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Main$lvMyAccount$ctrl17$lnkDelete','')`? I also had this problem last year, I just gave up. =(

Comment: The short answer is *no*. You can't get the link if it's generated by javascript.

Comment: no no, i dnt want that link. i wanna get rid of that also. i have been trying that from past 2 days, but not able to ...Can u help me?

Comment: I think you do want the link.. The url to the next page is in the link, remember?

Comment: yeah, sorry that ans was not for u, it was for @justhalf, askn abt delete links. :)

Comment: look in the console/network tab of your browser for the ajax that is fired on clicking that link manually, it will give you the url of the page it is accessing, you can use this to determine their url paging structure... just a guess but that's what I normally do

Comment: no ajax control are been used :(

Comment: your browser must be making a network connection to get the content of the next page, no? this will be recorded somewhere, usually the network tab in chrome.... just a suggestion, but maybe I'm not understanding you properly

Comment: fine. let me try this, but even i m not sure. but one thing i have seen, all the pages have the same URL, there is not difference.

Comment: just pull the page number out from the scrape then and plug it into your known url, they may change their urls down the line but that's the price you pay for scraping someone else's site.

Comment: hmm true. i guess its the same i m doing.

Comment: can anyone help me in this?